# Why my cloud function does not work anymore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello I got the following error in my Cloud Functions:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials.
```

when i execute a cloud function, but before saturday that functions works correctly and i dont know why it changes.
Also i got the next notifications in firebase console:

```
Function execution started

Function execution took 56 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related [to communication with the metadata server](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/798).

As a temporary solution, [you can create a service account rather than relying on the default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

The credentials need to be available in a file or disk, so you would need to use either the API to deploy your project, or use the file upload option.

At this point you would set your credentials to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./my-service-account.json

Or you can load your service account credentials manually like the following:

```
Const credentials = require(‘./credentials.json’)
admin. initialize App({
    Credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials),
    databaseURL: “https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com”
})
```